# what is wrong with the gcc internal symbol decoration?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>

namespace myname{
    double var = 42;
}

extern "C" double _ZN6myname3varE = 10.0;

int main(){
    printf("%d\n", _ZN6myname3varE);
    return 0;
}
```

The `gcc` compile result is:

```
Jim@ubuntu:~/workspace/vi_edit$ g++ testSymble.cpp -o testSymble
testSymble.cpp:7:19: warning: ‘_ZN6myname3varE’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]
testSymble.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
testSymble.cpp:10:32: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘double’ [-Wformat]
/tmp/cczIjRfH.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cczIjRfH.s:14: Error: symbol `_ZN6myname3varE' is already defined
```

Why `_ZN6myname3varE` is redefined?
What does the warning `‘_ZN6myname3varE’ initialized and declared ‘extern’ [enabled by default]` mean?

---

If the program declares or defines a name in a context where it is reserved, other than as explicitly allowed by this clause, the behavior is undefined.

**17.4.3.1.2 Global names**
Each name that contains a double underscore (_ _) or begins with an underscore followed by an uppercase
letter (2.11) is reserved to the implementation for any use.

Comment: Symbol names beginning with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter (like `_Zxyz...`) are reserved for use by the implementation (i.e. the compiler toolchain).  Simply by declaring or defining such a symbol results in *undefined behavior* (C99 §7.1.3/1-2, C++03 §17.4.3.1/1, §17.4.3.1.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first warning message means that if you include `extern` in a variable's declaration, you cannot also include an initializer.  Thus, both these lines generate that warning:

```
extern "C" int i = 9;
extern     int j = 10;
```

You can either write:

```
int i = 9;
int j = 10;
```

or:

```
extern "C" int i;
extern     int j;
```

or (as [Adam Rosenfield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9530/adam-rosenfield) points out in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17691220/what-is-wrong-with-the-gcc-internal-symbol-decoration/17691259#comment25776638_17691259)), you can include braces in the line to allow an initializer:

```
extern "C" { int i = 9; }
```

Applied to your code, you cannot put the initializer `= 42` in the `extern "C"` line, or you need to write:

```
extern "C" { double _ZN6myname3varE = 10.0; }
```

In isolation, and ignoring the final issue, that should 'work'.

The second warning means that `namespace myname { double var = 42; }` is a `double` so the `%d` conversion specification is wrong; it should be `%f` or `%e` or `%g` or variants on this theme.

```
printf("%f\n", myname::var);
```

The third message, the error, is from the assembler.  Because the first message was only a warning, you actually have two different definitions which, when mangled, translate to `_ZN6myname3varE`, with two different initializers.  You're only allowed one definition — the One Definition Rule.

However, names starting with an underscore followed by an upper-case letter are reserved for the implementation, so by trying to use the name `_ZN6myname3varE` directly, you are invoking undefined behaviour.  Don't mess around with undefined behaviour; avoid it.

Answer (score 3):

> Why `_ZN6myname3varE` is redefined?

The C++ variable `myname::var` is [name-mangled](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_C.2B.2B) to `_ZN6myname3varE` by GCC.  You've also defined a C (i.e. non-mangled) variable called `_ZN6myname3varE`.  Therefore you have multiple definitions of the same symbol.

---

> What does the warning *[...]* mean?

Standard usage is:

**foo.h**

```
extern "C" int myvariable;
```

**foo.c/cc**

```
#include "foo.h"

int myvariable = 42;
```

I'm not sure whether the C++ standard permits initialization of `extern "C"` variables (i.e. like you're doing).  But the compiler is certainly warning you that what you're doing probably doesn't make sense.

Comment: What about the warning part?

Comment: @Zack That's because it doesn't make sense to initialize  an `extern` variable.

Comment: When initialize an extern variable, it is the same as defining a new one. Can I say it?

Comment: A single-line language linkage specification like `extern "C" int x;` is always considered a declaration, whereas brace-enclosed linkage specification like `extern "C" { int x; }` can be a declaration or a definition.  Since initializers can only be present in definitions, you must use a brace-enclosed specification to define and initialize a global variable with C linkage (C++03 7.5/7).